# Nesting with SASS does not seem to work for me?

Tags: html, css, sass

So I have been trying to get SASS to work for a project, but for some reason the nesting does not want to work for me?

When I move the snippets for the .header-menu outside of the nest it works perfectyl fine, just not nested?

> This is the code for the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/scss/style.scss">
    <script src="../Javascript/includeHTML.es6"></script>
</head>

<header>
    <div w3-include-html="../Elements/Header.html"></div>
    <script>includeHTML()</script>
</header>


<body class="homepage">
<p>hallo dit is een test</p>
</body>

</html>
```

> This is the code for the Header file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/scss/style.scss">
</head>

<header>
<div class="header">
    <h1>Pointbreak</h1>

    <div class="header-menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Who am I?</li>
            <li>My work</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
</header>

</html>
```

> this is the style.scss, note that neither of the '&-menu' nor '.header-menu' works:

```css
.header {
  background-color: white;

  &-menu {
    background-color: red;
  }

  .header-menu {
    background-color: orange;
  }
}

.homepage {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

> and lastly the compiled CSS code:

```css
.header {
  background-color: white;
}
.header-menu {
  background-color: red;
}
.header .header-menu {
  background-color: orange;
}

.homepage {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

I hope I have supplied enough information, if not please let me know.

Diorcula

> **EDIT**
>   hereby i supply an image of my chrome webdev tools Network tab:
>   [image: webdev NETWORK]
>
> Also the version of SASS i use is: 1.25.0
>   and the version of NPM is: 6.13.0

Comment: In short, what you want is `.header .header-menu` compiled instead of `.header-menu`?

Comment: Is there a style overriding what you put in? Do you have another CSS file that may be causing this? This could also be a cache issue.

Comment: In addition to the questions above, are you seeing the compiled CSS file loaded properly into your webpage? (see the Network tab in DevTools to be sure)

Comment: @Azametzin in short what I want is to be able to nest my styling, since the div "header-menu" is inside the div: "header" and i want to be able to layout my styling the same way so if i have more divs inside "header" i can easily add the syling for them to de header div. if this clarifies some

Comment: @disinfor no i have already checked that en emptied my cache, but no difference what so ever

Comment: @chriskirknielsen i will post an edit for this in the question with an image, but everything is fine there as far is i can notice

Comment: I voted to close this question, because it's a typo situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

So after a good night sleep i found the asnwer,
you guys were all right in some way and it encouraged me to look somewhere else.

The problem was that i was linking the wrong stylesheet, that i found out only after looking at the Network requests in the DevTools.

There i saw that it was loading the style.scss file, while the browser cannot read this of course. it should have been the CSS file.

> So i changed the folder and file from:
>
> ```html
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/scss/style.scss">
> ```
>
> To:
>
> ```html
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/css/style.css">
> ```

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can place another `&` at beginning of `&-menu` to nest it inside `.header`.

```
.header {
  background-color: white;

  & &-menu {
    background-color: red;
  }

  .header-menu {
    background-color: orange;
  }
}
```

Compiled CSS:

```css
.header {
  background-color: white;
}
.header .header-menu {
  background-color: red;
}
.header .header-menu {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't have to nest it. The compiled code they provided *should* work as expected. Especially with such a simple layout. I suspect there is something else going on..maybe an overriding style or a typo in the real code.

Comment: Yes, this question needs more details.

Comment: @Azametzin what details would you like to have more to be able to help? maybe i can provide them.